# Android design - multiple simple activities or complex single activity

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have a small application that sequentially starts multiple alarms (`AlarmManager`) with different parameters. For example, as soon as alarm one is finalized, alarm two is started. Then the flow would be something like this:

[image: Application flow]

Considering the Android life-cycle, what is the best way of implementing this application?

1. Having a single activity that handles the different alarms and states with variables or
2. calling different activities for each different alarm?

The views are simple and very similar (reusable).

**EDIT**: In the single activity scenario, what would happen if the application is then killed? The `AlarmManager` would still call the application, but I would loose the state and I'd be back to first step, wouldn't it?

Comment: It the layout same and have different viewGroup widgets on it, e.g buttons, images and texview change but layout remains same?

Comment: The layout is very similar, the only difference is the string displayed which varies depending on the respective alarm.

Comment: Definitely no need for new activity.

Comment: If your worried about code complexity, best solution is name conventions and organizing code into functions rather than orphans chuncks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the defining features of activities is that they are easy to navigate to and away from. I'd say that you should be better off using a single complex activity, because otherwise you would have to tackle the activity back-stack. 
It doesn't seem that you want to be able to navigate back from alarm 2 to alarm 1, which means that using separate activities is pretty pointless.